# PHP: file_get_contents() HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request from google maps api

Tags: php, google-maps

I want to make a http request but i always get

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

here is my code for the request

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Einsteinufer63,10587,Berlin&key=AIzaSyDBA9EWB_zNWC6XjDu9mGyIuuV6QSL_ABM');

var_dump($json);
```

Comment: Please try this code:

`<?php $json = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Einsteinufer63,10587,Berlin&key=AIzaSyDBA9EWB_zNWC6XjDu9mGyIuuV6QSL_ABM");
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($json);die;?>`

Comment: What happens if you manually load `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Einsteinufer63,10587,Berlin&key=AIzaSyDBA9EWB_zNWC6XjDu9mGyIuuV6QSL_ABM` in your browser, or using wget/curl?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the modified code i used urlencode() function for address
because if in case you are having space or some special characters in address then google api wont works by the above way

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode("Einsteinufer63,10587,Berlin").'&key=AIzaSyDBA9EWB_zNWC6XjDu9mGyIuuV6QSL_ABM');
    var_dump($json);
?>
```